# Apache server not starting but in Eclipse it shows starting

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I have installed **Apache Tomcat** server in my "D:" drive and **Eclipse** is configured with it. When I start the server from **Eclipse** it shows started.

[image]

But when I enter

```
http://localhost:8080
```

It shows following error and not load the Apache server.
[image]

the **netstat** shows the following.

[image]

So how can I fix this. Need some help. Thank you!

Comment: Are u sure that the server is started and importantly listening on 8080 port? Have you tried to use netstat command to confirm the same?

Comment: Eclipse shows the server is started and I didn't try netstat.

Comment: The server is started and listening on the port 8080, otherwise he will se the browser error 500. He is receiving a Tomcat error message. @SamanthaWithanage Have you checked your webapp structure? Or on the server page at eclipse (double click on the server) Have you marked the option "Use tomcat Installation" ?

Comment: netstat not showing the port 8080. I will post the command prompt. So whats wrong with it. Thank you.

Comment: Tomcat has started, but what webapps have been deployed?  Usually your will call your webapp like `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp`

Comment: no no. When I enter  http://localhost:8080/  It should display Apache tomcat, but in this case its not.

Comment: You must be missing ROOT webapp in tomcat webapps directory that is why you are getting 404 for root context path. Please check this or deploy your own webapp in root context.

Comment: @SamanthaWithanage you are running Tomcat from eclipse in that case, the default tomcat project is not available therefor you are not able to see Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running Tomcat from eclipse in that case, the default tomcat project is not available therefor you are not able to see Apache Tomcat.

So you need to try accessing your app as `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp`. And if you want to see the Apache Tomcat UI than start the Apache Tomcat from the bin folder using startup.bat file or an application exe which shows you CMD prompt (black screen). But than to access your `myWebApp` than you must deploy it in Apache tomcat's webapps folder.

You may also want to configure the welcone-file or load-on-startup servlet if you are using jsp-servlet technology.

For further information please refer official documentation from Apache Tomcat or search on Google/YouTube for visual examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps,

1. Try with your your_machine_ipaddress:8080

   **OR**
2. Try with different port say 8181.

   - Go to tomcat_installed_directory/conf/server.xml
   - Search for the string "connector port=" and change the port from 8080 to 8181
   - Restart the tomcat and try with localhost:8181 or localhost:8181/yourwebappname or your_machine_ipaddress:8181

   OR
3. If you are behind proxy server and trying to access tomcat running in some other machine, then add the ip address of the machine where tomcat is running to your browser bypass proxy.

Comment: I tried but had no rusalt. could be some wrong with my server. Thanks !

Comment: may be try with new installation of tomcat. By the way what version of tomcat you are using and what is the OS?

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0.12 server and the Os I'm using is Windows 8. I thing they are compatible each other. aren't they.

Comment: hope so. But have not used windows 8. apache tomcat 6 has limitations in Windows 7. So i feel apache tomcat 7 may have limitation in windows 8. Try with apache tomcat 8 from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi